# Google sheets script for erasing a timestamp after the cell is cleared

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, timestamp, reverse

I have a sheet counting drinks. I need to timestamp every drink entered by the user in separate column. I have done this using the script below. My problem is when the user deletes a drink (cell empty again) the timestamp is still there and messes with the calculations. I need the timestamp to be erased when the cell is erased.

```js
var timezone = "GMT";
var timestamp_format = "k:mm"; // Timestamp Format. 
var datestamp_format = "d/M";
var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('My sheet'); //Name of the sheet where you want to run this script.

var questionArray = ['drink 1', 'drink 2', 'drink 3','drink 4', 'drink 5', 'drink 6','drink 7', 'drink 8', 'drink 9','drink 10', 'drink 11', 'drink 12','drink 13','drink 14'];
var responseArray = ['Timestamp 1', 'Timestamp 2', 'Timestamp 3', 'Timestamp 4', 'Timestamp 5', 'Timestamp 6', 'Timestamp 7', 'Timestamp 8','Timestamp 9','Timestamp 10','Timestamp 11', 'Timestamp 12', 'Timestamp 13', 'Timestamp 14'];

var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
var index = actRng.getRow();
var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();//get values and place them inside array 
var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName); //get index position inside the array

for(var i = 0; i < questionArray.length ; i ++){   
   if (headers[0].indexOf(responseArray[1]) > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == (headers[0].indexOf(questionArray[i])+1) ) { // only timestamp if 'Last Updated' header exists, but not in the header row itself!
       var cell = sheet.getRange(index, (headers[0].indexOf(responseArray[i])+1) ); 
       var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
       cell.setValue(date); 
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on (free of sensitive information)? From the small explanation and the code you provided, I'm not sure I understand what's going on here.

Comment: Do users delete drink entries manually? Please be more specific